# Windows 10 has different displaynames for same timezones

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp

In an .net UWP-app (only Win 10) I'm displaying the `displayname` of timezones by iterating over the generic  `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimezones()` list. For example on my Windows 10 machines I will see:

```
(UTC+08:00)Perth
```

as the displayname.

However, on serveral other machines (same Windows-Version, same build, different Windows installation language) I'll see:

```
Perth
```

While I'm fully aware that the TimeZones are reflecting the avaible local system timezones, I cannot understand why the Displayname property of the same timezone object is different.

The [Windows-API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.displayname(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The display name is localized based on the culture installed with the Windows operating system.

Which is also cool for me, but does the culture remove also the UTC offset?

**Update:**

Here is one example (on Surface Pro 4, 1703, 15063.413) [image: Example]

Comment: Those are *display* names, meant solely to present the user with a human-readable representation. The `TimeZoneInfo` object still stores the correct time zone offset.

Comment: I tested two devices that installed different language, the UTC offset still exist and only display named localized. So on what device this API can lost time zone's base offset as you said?

Comment: @IInspectable I have to present the UTC offset to the user

Comment: @FikLi timezones change all the time. Russia has changed its timezones at least three times in the past 5 years. Venezuela changed its own only last year. You *can't* depend on the *display* names. In fact, if you really care about timezones, don't use Windows timezone names at all. The de-facto standard is IANA's timezone database (tzdb). Use a library like NodaTime that includes tzdb and keeps it up to date whenever there are changes

Comment: @FikLi as for the localized display name, that [comes from the registry](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,81) and a resource dll. Someone could even change this by hand, or it could change the next time time zones change and the list is updated by a Windows Update. Check `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` on the machines that don't show the offset.

Comment: This comes out of the registry, Panagiotis showed the registry key name.  The Display property contains the string and can be arbitrarily changed.  Beware of the Win10 Creators update that is being deployed lately, it is causing a lot of havoc and not all machines get the update at the same time.

Comment: If you need to present the UTC offset to the user, then do so. This information is available to you. Do not make any assumptions about whether or not the display name contains this information.